# Having trouble understanding subsets in python

Tags: python

i need someone to explain this for me.
Problems is

You are given two sets, A and B.
Your job is to find whether set A is a subset of set B.

If set A is subset of set B, print True.
If set A is not a subset of set B, print False.

```
for _ in range(int(input())):
     x, a, z, b = input(), set(input().split()), input(), set(input().split())
     print(a.issubset(b))
```

I don't understand why is there is an additional x and z and why do we need four input like `input()` for x and `input()` for z when all the question ask is whether or not the `input` of `set` a is  a subset of `set` b

When i try to delete the two input which is x and z from the python file because i thought it is not necessary, i got a wrong answer, please explain to me why.

Comment: It doesn't.  Your code works just as well with `a,  b =  set(input().split()), set(input().split())`.  HOWEVER, if this is a class assignment, and you are feeding input from a file, it may be that the extra `input()`s are there to match the format of the file.

Comment: yeah you are correct, thank for explaining, i have had a read again at the problems and understand why it had four input.